# JavaScript Objects Error using dot notation

Tags: javascript, object

```
$(document.body).on("click",'.sub-unfollow', function(){
  var unfollow_tag = {element:"",un:"",type:"",text:""};
  var unfollow_tag.element = $(this).parents("li");
  var unfollow_tag.un = $(this).parents("li").attr("data-un");
  var unfollow_tag.type = $(this).parents("li").attr("data-type");
  var unfollow_tag.text = $(this).parents("li").text();
  alert(unfollow_tag.text);
});
```

Getting an error with this seemingly basic object setup. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: "An error", what error?

Comment: Not actually sure, but no js is running on my page when this block of code is present. It only begins to work when i delete all references to unfollow_tag object

Comment: Have a look at the console.

Comment: Look in the dev console, learn to use a debugger

Comment: Why all those `var`s? You `var` the object, not the properties.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you Abhitalks.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `var` after once declaring `unfollow_tag`, it redeclares it instead of trying to access a property.

```
$(document).on("click",'.sub-unfollow', function(){
  var unfollow_tag = {};
  unfollow_tag.element = $(this).parents("li");
  unfollow_tag.un = $(this).parents("li").attr("data-un");
  unfollow_tag.type = $(this).parents("li").attr("data-type");
  unfollow_tag.text = $(this).parents("li").text();
  alert(unfollow_tag.text);
});
```